# How to set external display as the main one with MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Someone gives me old macbook with broken screen model white 7.1.

i get this mac as my computer i use it for study programming.

as monitor i use external monitor AOC 1080p. for connecting i use mini display port

So my problem or this problem of all mac notebooks i don't know.

So when i get this mac to sleep and sometime after i try turn it on it gets black screen.

now a days when i turn it off and next day try turn on it start with low resolution it loads with grey apple and then it shows black screen.

and after NVRAM or PRAM or SMC reseting and with 2 or 3 time it only load 
normal resolution and load OS.

my Question is:

it possible some how make this mac book understand that external monitor is main monitor and always load proper resolution like this be a mac mini.

later i want rebuild this macbook to look like mac mini and it bugs it's impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [Disable the Internal Screen on a MacBook Pro or Air in OS X Yosemite & Mavericks](http://osxdaily.com/2011/09/14/disable-the-internal-screen-on-a-macbook-pro-or-air-in-mac-os-x-10-7-lion/) to prevent the Mac from using the internal monitor the following command need to be run

```
# in OSX 10.9 
sudo nvram boot-args="iog=0x0"

# in OSX 10.10/10.11
sudo nvram boot-args="niog=1"

# to undo
sudo nvram -d boot-args
```

then restart.

Answer (score 1):

If you use you MacBook Pro in clam shell mode, your external monitor will automatically be the primary (and only) display.

See [Apple's instructions on clam shell mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201834) for more details.

Comment: my macbook is white and model is 7.1 which means 2010 year. my internal notebook monitor i was fully disconnect with all antenas and i have only bottom side. thats the problem only one monitor and when i set a password it stop recognize when it loads from vesa mode

Comment: i need understand how to make external monitor fully main like it's on mac mini for example. you putting monitor and start working with any problem after sleep or when just turning on